# Curl from a list

Tags: bash, shell, curl

I've a list.txt of id and I need to make a loop of curl.

This is the idea.

I've this :

```
3cTRKoZZIQYaNS3DYlHEFR
25azzh7Pgj9h91jufwTWcV
4slU5ipq2nzSZx5QrV8li5
5C2j8zYjGFil9cDVzz0BMD
6eO2p08CHHIdlUcwIVyelv
```

I need to run this command

```
curl -X GET "https://api.spotify.com/v1/albums/(ID)" -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer MyToken" > ./track.txt
```

What command I need to make to use the id from my filelist to curl ?

Thanks

Comment: Do you *need* `curl` or can you use `wget` too?

Comment: Hi,

Looks like the API of Spotify is curl only